# Creating regex to extract 4 digit number from string using java

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

Hi I am trying to build one regex to extract 4 digit number from given string using java. I tried it in following ways:

```
String mydata = "get the 0025 data from string";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+$");
    //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-90-90-90-9]+$");
    //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\d]+$");
    //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\d\\d\\d\\d]+$");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
    String val = "";
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));

        val = matcher.group(1);
    }
```

But it's not working properly. How to do this. Need some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change you pattern to:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})");
```

`\d` is for a digit and the number in `{}` is the number of digits you want to have.

Comment: Would it not be better to drop the parentheses and use `group(0)`? (micro-optimization, true, but when dealing with more complex patterns, it could come in handy)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to end up with **0025**,

```
String mydata = "get the 0025 data from string";
mydata = mydata.replaceAll("\\D", ""); // Replace all non-digits
```

Comment: this is the best and easiest approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[0-9]+\\b");
```

This should do it for you.`^$` will compare with the whole string.It will match string with only `numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the anchors.. put paranthesis if you want them in `group 1`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)");   //"[0-9]{4}" for 4 digit number
```

And extract out `matcher.group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Many better answers, but if you still have to use in the same way.

```
String mydata = "get the 0025 data from string";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<![-.])\\b[0-9]+\\b(?!\\.[0-9])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
String val = "";
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));

        val = matcher.group(0);
    }
```

changed `matcher.group(1);` to `matcher.group(0);`

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `\d{4}` or `[0-9]{4}` but note that by specifying the `^` at the beginning of regex and `$` at the end you're limiting yourself to strings that contain **only** 4 digits.

My recomendation: Learn some regex basics.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
HashMap<String,String> a=new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> b=new ArrayList<>();
String s=sc.nextLine();
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\d{4}");
Matcher m=p.matcher(s);

while(m.find())
{
    String x="";
    x=x+(m.group(0));
    a.put(x,"0");
    b.add(x);
}
System.out.println(a.size());
System.out.println(b);
```

You can find all matched digit patterns and unique patterns (for unique use `Set<String> k=b.keySet();`)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to match any number of digits then use pattern like the following:

```
^\D*(\d+)\D*$
```

And for exactly 4 digits go for

```
^\D*(\d{4})\D*$
```

Comment: *Try something like* are you not sure about it?

Comment: Okay - corrected (The original question used as well expression "...I tried it in following ways:...")